# Power BI - Facebook Ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get my facebook marketing data into power bi. I used Klipfolio before and there it just worked. Now I get this error:

```
"(#274) The ad account is not enabled for usage in Ads API. Please add it in     developers.facebook.com/apps -> select your app -> settings -> advanced ->     advertising accounts -> Ads API. Account XXXXXX not enabled for this     application."
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: Do what the error message say?

Comment: But I do not have an app

Comment: Then you need to create one.

Comment: So where do you get the error? And when?